# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isn't showing centre of preview

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession

I'm trying to display a video preview for a custom camera view in my app, however at the moment the preview is very much off centre - especially noticeable when using the front camera.

I'm positioning it like so:

```
if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
    previewLayer.bounds = scanningView.bounds
    previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(scanningView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(scanningView.bounds))
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    scanningView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, atIndex: 0)
}
```

However the centre of the preview is not in the centre of the view it is in. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Where did you write this initializing, I mean in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you try in viewDidAppear?

Comment: It's fine in viewDidAppear but it's a bit slow to initialise, so i guess i'll just initialise it in viewdidload and add to view in viewDidAppear

Comment: In viewDidLoad, autolayout hasn't been finished doing its job, so your `scanningView` doesn't have its final position and bounds. I had this issue before and I couldn't find a better place for positioning the preview layer, maybe someone has better solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need the CGRectGetMidX/Y just place give the preview layer a frame equal to the hosting view.

```
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
scanningView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

Also, you using auto layout? If so you might want adjust the frame when viewWillLayoutSubviews gets called

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    previewLayer.frame = scanningView.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a layer and setting frame it seems better to use custom UIView and assign its subLayer class to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. See the example [below](https://github.com/kelvinlauKL/CustomCameraDemo/blob/master/CustomCameraView/PreviewView.swift)

```
final class PreviewView: UIView {

  // 1
  override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
      }
.
.
```

I found the solution this way.